# Ubuntu 18.04 with a PC tracking mechanism is still a "free software"?

Tags: ubuntu, data

I read [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-data-collection-opt-out) that basically says the Ubuntu 18.04 will include a mechanism that collects the following basic data on a user:

- Which version of Ubuntu you’re installing (including which flavour)
- Whether you have network connectivity
- Hardware stats, including CPU, RAM, GPU, etc
- Your device vendor (e.g., Dell, Lenovo, etc)
- Your country
- How long your install took to complete
- Whether you have auto login enabled
- Your disk layout
- Whether you chose to install third party codecs
- Whether you chose to download updates during install

The author says (maybe sarcastically) that this data will be available to everyone `Ubuntu will make the results of the data public, for everyone to see`.

Although No one can see what goes inside your operating system and no action history is documented anywhere, isn't such implementation take out the Free Software element out of Ubuntu?

I'm not sure if sharing the aforementioned data might go against the concept of Free Software as defined by the Free Software Foundation (FSF) and promoted by [Richard Stallman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman) in many of his lectures, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ag1AKIl_2GM&t=12s).

Comment: There seems to be a confusion between the terms "Free Software" and "Privacy". They do not have much to do with each other, or rather, they are mostly independent of each other.

Comment: I assume that this is not a Stallmanian stance, @Kusalananda. I'm quite surprised to see so many in the *nix community disagree with Stallamn.

Comment: Strong personalities with strong views generate disagreements. Another such person in the Unix world is Theo de Raadt (and there are many many more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt they'd like it a lot, but as far as I can tell, their [definition of "free software"](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) mentions no such things. Besides, with free software, you're free to fix such misfeatures if you don't like them.

That said, there are many other things the FSF considers non-free. Take a look at [the list of Linux distributions the FSF considers free](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html). (Spoiler: Ubuntu isn't there). Frankly, I hadn't heard of any of them before peeking at the list just now.

They also have [a list of the more common distributions, the ones people have actually heard about](https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.html), including the reasons they consider them non-free. (Spoiler: it includes Ubuntu. And Arch, Debian, Fedora, Gentoo and Red Hat, among others. Plus all the three big BSDs.)

So, my answer would be: maybe, but who cares.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, no, it does not:

Firstly, users of the distribution can opt out of providing the requested data with no adverse effects.

As stated in the [initial announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2018-February/040139.html):

> We would like to add a checkbox to the installer, exact wording TBD,
>   but along the lines of “Send diagnostics information to help improve
>   Ubuntu”. This would be checked by default.
>
> [...]
>
> Any user can simply opt out by unchecking the box, which triggers one
>   simple POST stating, “`diagnostics=false`”.  There will be a
>   corresponding checkbox in the Privacy panel of GNOME Settings to
>   toggle the state of this.

Secondly, the software included and provided by the repositories is unchanged.  Presuming that Ubuntu without the user data is considered to be "free software", this is unchanged by -- *optional* -- metrics tracking being included in the installation process.

That said, one's answer to this question is highly subjective.

Answer (score 2):

For software to be free, all that’s necessary is for it to be distributed (legally) under a free software license. What software *does* is irrelevant.

There are of course different definitions of what constitutes a free software license, but the broad strokes are all similar; see for example [the Free Software Definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), [the Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines), and [the Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd).

Comment: Stephen, I never worked with Debian desktop but through your answer I understand that the Free Software Foundation (FSS) stallmanian definition is slightly different then the Debian community one.